# SQL query for find out in/out time in a office

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may be silly question for the DATABASE guys but for me its very tough because it's the first time when I am seeing the DATABASE..I am not the DATABASE guy but I have to do this.

I have DATABASE in SQL SERVER 2005 and there is a VIEW that contain the data related to employee in/out in the office.

[image]

There may be more then 2 entry in a day for a particular date but we consider first entry in a day is in time in the office and last entry as the out time from the office,In between these these employee can go out side any no of time but we consider only first and last time entry in a day.

So I have to to write QUERY for this...

**EDIT :**

List of coloumns in a view some other coloumn are also there but I do'nt think it is necessary to describe here ..

- CardSrNo
- LastName
- FirstName
- MidleName
- PersonalID
- Date
- Time
- YMD
- HMS
- CardNumber
- Department

Comment: How do you distinguish between IN entry vs OUT entry. The screen shot does not convey that information.

Comment: Have a look at a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) to learn the SQL basics and pay attention to the MIN and MAX statements.

Comment: from the CardNumber and the Date we can fetch the corresponding entry and then we can fetch first and last time as in and out.......am I right........

Comment: @vikky Can you provide a list of columns in that table/view?

Comment: @peterm see the edit part.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am using that query :

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,CardNumber,Department, Date , MIN(Time) AS intime , MAX(Time) AS outtime ,
convert(varchar(8),(convert(datetime,MAX(Time),110) - convert(datetime,MIN(Time),110)),108) AS Duration
FROM CARDENTRYEXITTRANSACTIONVIEW
GROUP BY FirstName, Date,LastName,CardNumber,Department
```

And its give the perfect result............

Answer (score 1):

Try a good ol' [`group by`.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
Select employeeID, Date,
    MIN(Time) as InTime, 
    MAX(Time) as OutTime
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY employeeID, Date
```

Comment: Mitch, I think this needs to be grouped by Date as well

Comment: @MarkOrmston, this was meant only as an example.  The screenshot does not provide a column listing, and I would hope that there is a consolidated Date/Time column, but yes, if they are separate, additional work is necessary.

Comment: Gotcha. I was about to answer when you did, but it does look like Date is separate in the screen shot from Time, possibly done that way to make it easier to do what he's asking and I didn't want to muck with your answer, so figured I'd just tell you and let you get the answer.

Comment: @Mitch can you tell me what is the transactionDate here and I think we need to group by it by Date also

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) ranking function to determine first and last time entry

```
  ;WITH cte AS
 (                             
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonalID ORDER BY [Date] ASC, [Time] ASC) AS rnASC,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonalID ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Time] DESC) AS rnDESC
  FROM dbo.your_tableName
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rnASC = 1 OR rnDESC = 1
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ef0/2)

OR use option with [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.105%29.asp) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.your_tableName t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.your_tableName t2
              WHERE t1.PersonalID = t2.PersonalID
              HAVING (t1.[Date] = MAX(t2.[Date]) AND t1.[Time] = MAX(t2.[Time]))
                OR (t1.[Date] = MIN(t2.[Date]) AND t1.[Time] = MIN(t2.[Time]))
              )
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f4c3/1)

Comment: Min, Max, or TOP would, to me, be much more natural than a dual Row_Number.

Comment: @ErikE give me demo please;)very interestingly

Comment: @ErikE estimate my new jet request)