# SQL calculation time in the office

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with all the log files for users to enter and leave the office.
Currently I use the min and max function to calculate the working hour for each user at each day.

If I need to calculate the exact time that a user stayed in the office, where can I start?

Currently I have no clue on how to start.

Not everybody have one record of in and then out. Sometimes system may have 2 IN or 2 Out.
If this case happens then the working hour for that date will be o.

```
    Date Occurred   Time Occurred   First Name  Last Name   Location

    9/1/2014        10:39:40        User A      User A      OfficeIn
    9/1/2014        12:34:36        User A      User A      OfficeOut
    9/1/2014        12:37:49        User A      User A      OfficeIn
    9/1/2014        12:39:51        User A      User A      OfficeOut
    9/1/2014        12:42:19        User A      User A      OfficeIn
    9/1/2014        14:09:32        User A      User A      OfficeIn
    9/1/2014        16:15:30        User A      User A      OfficeOut
    9/1/2014        16:17:40        User A      User A      OfficeIn
    9/1/2014        17:43:43        User A      User A      OfficeOut
```

Comment: You cannot "calculate the exact time that a user stayed in the office" if your data is incomplete, you can only make assumptions. As to what assumptions you make, this may depend on the sort of boss you are, local employment laws and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So with the records in the order shown, you would like to look into the previous record in order to calculate the time span. LAG is the SQL function that looks into the previous record.

For every OfficeOut record where the previous record is OfficeIn I calculate the time difference. Then I sum up all gained time parts per user. As you separate date and time (why???) I must first combine them. As there is no person ID in the table, but just first and last name, let's hope that their combination is unique.

```
select 
  name,
  sum
  (
    case when location = 'OfficeOut'
    and lag(location) over(partition by name order by when) = 'OfficeIn' then
        datediff(minutes, lag(when) over(partition by name order by when)
    end
  ) as total_minutes
from
(
  select 
    concat(first_name, last_name) as name,
    location, 
    cast(date_occurred as datetime) + cast(time_occurred as datetime) as when
  from mytable
)
group by name
order by name;
```

Now to error detection. You want the sum to be 0 if there is an inconsistency. So me must look for records where the status is the same as in the previous record.

```
select 
  name,
  case when max(case when location = lag(location) over(partition by name order by when) then 'ERROR' end) = 'ERROR' then 
    0
  else
    sum
    (
      case when location = 'OfficeOut'
      and lag(location) over(partition by name order by when) = 'OfficeIn' then
          datediff(minutes, lag(when) over(partition by name order by when)
      end
    )
  end as total_minutes
from
(
  select 
    concat(first_name, last_name) as name,
    location, 
    cast(date_occurred as datetime) + cast(time_occurred as datetime) as when
  from mytable
)
group by name
order by name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the following links, it might help you - you ll get the idea how to do this -

[Working with Time Spans and Durations in SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server)

[SQL query for find out in/out time in a office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105954/sql-query-for-find-out-in-out-time-in-a-office)